# associate multiple values for one key in array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, dictionary

I have a text file that looks like:

```
1 aaaa
2 bbbb
3 cccc
4 dddd
2 eeee
2 ffff
4 gggg
```

I would like to map these into some sort of associative array so that I can access, for example, all the values associated with the key 2 and all the values associated with the key 4, etc.:

```
1->aaaa
2->bbbb,eeee,ffff
3->cccc
4->dddd,gggg
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to do this with 'declare -A MYMAP'. Is there some easy way to do this?

--------update--------

my key/value pairs look like this actually:

```
bb126.B1 bb126.1.ms.01
bb126.B2 bb126.1.ms.02
bb126.B3 bb126.1.ms.03
bb126.B4 bb126.1.ms.04
```

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: @l19 Well, I only know how to map one value to one key with declare MYMAP. How do I map multiple values to one key?

Comment: What do you need to do with the values later? Do you need to be able to get at them individually or just as one large string?

Comment: I have another file with a subset of the keys. I'm going to iterate over those keys in the other file and replace them with their sets of associated values (comma delimited).

Comment: Do the values ever contain whitespace?

Comment: No, they look like this: bb135.B1. And values look like: bb135.1.ms.15. There are multiple values for each key (bb135.1.ms.15, bb135.9.ms.15, ...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution with [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) and [Associative Arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays):

```
# store
declare -A array # this is the only update
while read key value; do
    array[$key]="${array[$key]}${array[$key]:+,}$value"
done < file
# print
for key in "${!array[@]}"; do echo "$key->${array[$key]}"; done
```

---

#### Explanation

```
array[$key]="${array[$key]}${array[$key]:+,}$value"
```

saves each `$value` in `array[$key]` separated by `,`:

- `${array[$key]}` save previous value(s) (if any).
- `${array[$key]:+,}` adds a `,` if there's a previous value.
- `$value` adds the new read value.

---

```
for key in "${!array[@]}"; do echo "$key->${array[$key]}"; done
```

prints the values associated to each `$key`.

---

From [`man bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> ${parameter:+word}
>       If parameter is null or unset, nothing is substituted, otherwise the expansion of word is substituted.
>
> ${!name[@]}
>   ${!name[*]}
>       If name is an array variable, expands to the list of array indices (keys) assigned in name. If name is not an array, expands to 0 if name is set and null otherwise. When ‘@’ is used and the expansion appears within double quotes, each key expands to a separate word.

---

#### Example

```
$ cat file
1 aaaa
2 bbbb
3 cccc
4 dddd
2 eeee
2 ffff
4 gggg

$ ./script.sh 
1->aaaa
2->bbbb,eeee,ffff
3->cccc
4->dddd,gggg
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I was wondering if there is a way to print a specific value only with a specific key and the value's index, eg. "ffff"

Answer (score -2):

The below script is for comma separated value, you can change as per your need

```
awk -F "," '{OFS=","} 1 {if (a[$1]) {a[$1] = a[$1]" "$2} else {a[$1] = $2}} END {for (i in a)  { print i,a[i]}}'  input_file > Output_file
```